# Selenium reading data from Excel file

Tags: java, excel, selenium, nullpointerexception

I am trying to read some test data from an Excel file (3 rows and 2 columns with no blank row in between) but in the output I am getting just the first row of the Excel. After that it is giving me a null pointer exception.

```
public class ReadDataFromExcel {

    public void readExcel(String filePath,String fileName,String sheetName) throws IOException {

        File file =    new File(filePath+"\\"+fileName);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        Workbook myWorkbook = null; 
        String fileExtensionName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));

        if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xlsx")) {
            myWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        }
        else if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xls")) {
            myWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);    
        }

        Sheet mySheet = myWorkbook.getSheet(sheetName);    
        int rowCount = mySheet.getLastRowNum()- guru99Sheet.getFirstRowNum();
        System.out.println("Total rows= " +rowCount);   

        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount+1; i++) {   
            Row row = mySheet.getRow(i);
            int columnCount = row.getLastCellNum() - row.getFirstCellNum();           

            for(int j=0; j <= columnCount; j++) {                               
                System.out.print(row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+"|| ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String...strings) throws IOException {

        ReadDataFromExcel objExcelFile = new ReadDataFromExcel();
        String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\testFileInputOutput";
        objExcelFile.readExcel(filePath,"testExcel.xlsx","testSheet");
    } 
}
```

I am getting the exception on this line:
 `System.out.print(row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+"|| ");`

Answer (score 0):

To get past NullPointerException you can check for null by replacing the line that is throwing the exception with this:

```
Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
if (cell != null) {
    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
}
System.out.print("|| ");
```